# Запятая в выражении

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед словом более: "новая, более мощная ракета"? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

***Новая, более мощная ракета.***

Запятая ставится, определения однородные, произношение с перечислительной интонацией.

Однородность определений можно объяснить **и по смыслу, и формально.**

1) Оба определения характеризуют предмет **независимо**: новая ракета, более мощная ракета. Определения сближены по значению, так как обозначают ряд признаков предмета.

Вариант ***новая, мощная ракета*** также пишется через запятую, это однородные определения. Если считать их неоднородными, то получится **новая (мощная ракета)**, то есть среди мощных ракет мы выбираем новую, что неверно по смыслу.

2) **Формально** же сочетание "новая, более мощная ракета" просто не может писаться без запятой, так как в**торое определение является сложным по форме** (фактически оно приравнивается к определительному **обороту**).

У Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_10.htm

1. Между однородными определениями, не связанными союзами, ставится запятая.

7) если за **одиночным** определением следует определение, выраженное **причастным оборотом**: малоизвестные, расположенные на отшибе курганы; твёрдый, плохо выбритый подбородок (ср. при другом порядке слов: плохо выбритый твёрдый подбородок).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.